# Are Bluetooth and/or NFC anonymous?

Tags: privacy, bluetooth, nfc

Suppose I have a smartphone and I have disabled all usual de-anonymizing things (e.g., wifi probe requests). My phone sends some data over Bluetooth (or NFC) to device A, and then at a different place and time, sends entirely independent data to device B.

If the owners of device A and B compare these two connections, can they conclude that it was the same device?

Answer (score 3):

Not anonymous. Yes, connected devices could compare hardware. Using the Bluetooth Address:

- https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics/how-bluetooth-works
- https://macaddresschanger.com/what-is-bluetooth-address-BD_ADDR

> Every single Bluetooth device has a unique 48-bit address, commonly
> abbreviated BD_ADDR. This will usually be presented in the form of a
> 12-digit hexadecimal value.

Comment: It is indeed likely that this could be used to make a comparison to break the anonymity. On the other hand, framing would be possible by spoofing the BD_ADDR, leaving room for plausible deniability.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to break the comparison (the second link suggests that that is true), but it is also possible that without a specific effort on the part of the device user, that the comparison can be made.